# When is a quotient by a strictly free group action étale?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-schemes

Let $S$ be a base scheme and $G$ an $S$-group scheme acting on an $S$-scheme $X$ and assume that the quotient scheme $Y := X/G$ exists. (This is for example the case if $S$ is finite locally free and the orbit of every closed point in $X$ is contained in an affine open subset, see (4.16) in [Moonens book on abelian varieties](https://www.math.ru.nl/~bmoonen/BookAV/Quotients.pdf))

I am interested in the question when $X \to Y$ is étale.

The first theorem in section II.7 of Mumfords book on abelian varieties answers this question for the case of algebraic varieties with an action of a finite group: The action has to be free in the sense that $g(x) \neq x$ for any $x \in X$ and $g \in G$.

For group schemes an action is called strictly free if the graph morphism
$$\psi : G \times_S X \to X \times_S X, \quad (g,x) \mapsto (g(x),x)$$
is a closed immersion, which implies that the stabilizer $G_x$ is trivial (see (4.2)(ii) in Moonen).
To me it seems like this is a reasonable requirement, but I don't see why it should be sufficient.

Assuming that $G$ acts strictly freely on $X$, which additional requirements do we need so that $X \to Y$ is étale?

For example, is anything known about the case when $G$ is diagonalizable, or at least equal to $\mathbb{G}_m$ or $\mu_n$?

Comment: "For example, is anything known about the case when $G$ is diagonalizable, or at least equal to $\mathbb{G}_m$ or $\mu_n$?"  The quotient by a free action of $\mathbb{G}_m$ has fibers of positive dimension.  Thus it is not etale.

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks. In hindsight this is not surprising, as $\mathbb{G}_m$ isn't even finite.

Comment: Maybe it would be more reasonable to ask under what conditions the quotient map $X\to X/G$ is, as a $G$-torsor, locally trivial in the étale topology. That actually is true in fair generality, by a theorem of Seshadri.